# How do I publish a UDP Port on Docker?

Tags: docker, udp

How do I forward a UDP port from my Docker container to the host machine?

Answer (score 275, accepted):

Use the -p flag and add `/udp` suffix to the port number.

`-p 53160:53160/udp`

Full command

```
sudo docker run -p 53160:53160 \
    -p 53160:53160/udp -p 58846:58846 \ 
    -p 8112:8112 -t -i aostanin/deluge /start.sh
```

If you're running boot2docker on Mac, be sure to forward the same ports on boot2docker to your local machine.

You can also document that your container needs to receive UDP using [EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) in The `Dockerfile` (EXPOSE does not publish the port):

```
EXPOSE 8285/udp
```

Here is a link with more Docker Networking info covered in the container docs:
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/
(Courtesy of Old Pro in the comments)

Comment: (rant) Literally nowhere in the official documentation, wow.

"-p=[]      : Publish a container᾿s port or a range of ports to the host
               format: ip:hostPort:containerPort | ip::containerPort | hostPort:containerPort | containerPort".        

Although the official example mentions " -p 1234-1236:1234-1236/tcp", there are no matches for "udp" or "protocol" on the whole [page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports).

Comment: @AlexanderGonchiy Not to excuse the documentation for docker run, but the general format for exposing ports it is referring to is covered in the [Container Networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) documentation.

Comment: Expose should only be the port/proto, not a port pair like you have work publish. And expose does not publish the port and is not needed to publish the port, it's documentation.

Answer (score 24):

Just thought I would pitch in for docker-compose config.

```
ports:
  - "9955:9955/udp"
```