# Communication between linked docker containers

Tags: linux, networking, docker, docker-compose

I have two docker containers in the following setup on a host machine:

- **Container 1** - UDP Port 5043 is mapped to host port 5043 (0.0.0.0:5043:5043)
- **Container 2** - Needs to send data to Container 1 on port 5043 as UDP.

#### Scenario 1

1. I start Container 1 and obtain it's IP address.
2. I use this IP address and configure Container 2 with it and start it.
3. Container 2 is able to send UDP data to Container 1 by calling `udp://Container_1_IP:5043`

EVERYTHING WORKS!!

#### Scenario 2

1. I start Container 1 by mapping 5043 UDP port to host's 5043 port (`0.0.0.0:5043:5043`)
2. I link Container 2 and Container 1 using '`--links`'.
3. Now, when Container 2 invokes the URL `udp://Container_1_IP:5043`, an error is thrown "`Connection refused`".
4. I did verify that I am able to ping the Container 1 from inside the Container 2 using the IP.

Any help to get the Scenario 2 working for me would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [Docker links](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#environment-variables):

> Docker also defines a set of environment variables for each port exposed by the source container.
>   Each variable has a unique prefix in the form:

```
<name>_PORT_<port>_<protocol>
```

> The components in this prefix are:
>
> - the alias  specified in the --link parameter (for example, webdb)
> - the `<port>` number exposed
> - **a `<protocol>` which is either TCP or UDP**

That means you need to make sure that Container1 exposes the right port with the right protocol (in your case, UDP): see "[How do I expose a UDP Port on Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27596409/6309)"