# Allow bootp for dnsmasq in docker container

Tags: docker, dnsmasq

I try to run dnsmasq which have to provide DHCP + BOOTP, 
but dnsmask doesn't open 67\udp port when it is running in container.

With similar configuration file on the host system it works properly.

I run container with flags -net host  and -privileged,  but it doesn't help me.

Why dnsmasq doesn't want to open 67/udp (BOOTP server)  into container?
How I able to fix it for doing that?

Comment: I found that dnsmasq uses raw socket,  but how it affects?

Comment: can you show your Dockerfile and your `docker run` command?

Comment: have a look at https://hub.docker.com/r/roninkenji/dnsmasq-docker/

Comment: I run it like:
docker run -d --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
-v /etc/cobbler:/etc/cobbler \
-v /var/lib/tftpboot:/var/lib/tftpboot \
-v /etc/xinetd.d:/etc/xinetd.d \
-v /var/lib/cobbler:/var/lib/cobbler \
 --net host \
48b8f78ab34d

Comment: I do not see the UDP port 67  in your `docker run` so?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596409/how-do-i-expose-a-udp-port-on-docker

Comment: there is parameter in  command  `--net host` . It'll provide host network to container.   I run `netstat` -an into container firstly,  and there is not open 67 port

Comment: having `--net host` means it shares the host interface with the container, but if you do not say the port 67 is published, so...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129627/discussion-between-user2915097-and-oleg-ilyin).

Comment: I add `-p 67:67/udp` for command which run it,   try to add `EXPOSE 67` in `Dockerfile`. it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the root cause isn't in docker configuration.
I missed to add configuration file /etc/dnsmasq.d/default.conf with required parameters. 
After adding it 67 port was opened and exposing began works