# How to read UDP stream in VLC from remote machine

Tags: networking, udp, gstreamer, vlc

There are lots of articles in google which describe how to read udp stream from localhost but I haven't faced any about how to do it from remote machine and just the way to change **host** to

> udp://@xxx.xx.xx.xx:5004

doesn't work.

I use simple gstreamer command to make a demo videotestsrc over udp from  [here](https://github.com/MDHSRobotics/TeamWiki/wiki/Gstreamer--Install-and-UDP-stream-instructions) and this works greatly over localhost but not from remote as I needed.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vv -e videotestsrc ! queue ! x264enc bitrate=5000 ! mpegtsmux alignment=7 ! rndbuffersize max=1316 min=1316 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5004
```

---

VLC read from **localhost**:

```
udp://@127.0.0.1:5004
```

VLC read from **remote** would like it to work but it doesn't :)

```
udp://@xxx.xx.xx.xx:5004
```

Want to stress that **tcp** works great for both localhost and remote and udp behaviour is totally strange.

Please, help and describe how to read UDP stream from remote machine.

Comment: UDP traffic on that port might be blocked by a firewall or not routed between your host and the remote.

Comment: @aergistal Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried different ports. I used docker for this purpose with port:port/udp. As here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596409/how-do-i-publish-a-udp-port-on-docker